vertically center frametitle in beamer headline
I was trying to get my frametitle vertically centered in the headline of my presentation. Essentially, this should happen by default but I have some titles on two lines as well as some with framesubtitle; for this reason, I had to add this line to center them vertically:
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-.1in}{}

The side effect is that it pushes all the way to the top my on-line titles, which otherwise would be centered. Since the overall structure has already a few custom settings, below a MWE.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{bground}{HTML}{005EB8}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber=1%
        {\begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
        \fill [color=bground] (0,0.668\paperheight) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \else%
        {\begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
        \fill [color=bground] (0,0.868\paperheight) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        \fi%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber=1%
        {\hfill\includegraphics[width=1.67in,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}\hspace{0in}\vspace{-1.25in}}
    \else%
        {\hfill\includegraphics[width=.67in,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}\hspace{0in}\vspace{-.5in}}
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@author[#1]#2{%
  \def\and{\tabularnewline}
  \def\insertauthor{\def\inst{\beamer@insttitle}\def\and{\tabularnewline}%
  \begin{tabular*}{.97\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cc}#2\end{tabular*}}%
  \def\beamer@shortauthor{#1}%
  \ifbeamer@autopdfinfo%
    \def\beamer@andstripped{}%
    \beamer@stripands#1 \and\relax
    {\let\inst=\@gobble\let\thanks=\@gobble\def\and{, }\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\beamer@andstripped}}}
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

\title[Ph.D. defense]{FIRST LINE \\ SECOND LINE \\ THIRD LINE}
\author[Surname, Given Name]{
\textbf{Candidate} & \textbf{Supervisors} \and
Given Name & Porf. X \and
Surname & Prof. Y}
\institute[]{\centering Ph.D. Program in \\ \dots \\ \rom{36}\textdegree cycle}
\date[\today]{\centering Academic Years yyyy/yyyy – yyyy/yyyy}
\logo{\includegraphics[height=.5in]{example-image-b}}

\setbeamerfont{title}{shape=\bfseries,size=\LARGE}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=anti-flashwhite}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=anti-flashwhite}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-.1in}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
    \vspace{-.45in}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overview}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\subsection{First subsection}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This title is \\ on two lines}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This title has}
\framesubtitle{a subtitle}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

My guessing is that I can/could do something in the \setbeamertemplate{headline} on the line of what suggested in other posts, for instance:
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \parbox{\paperwidth}{{\insertframetitle}{\insertframesubtitle}}
}
\makeatother

or
\makeatletter 
\long\def\beamer@@frametitle[#1]#2{% 
  \beamer@ifempty{#2}{}{% 
    \gdef\insertframetitle{{#2\ifnum\beamer@autobreakcount>0
        \relax{}\space\usebeamertemplate*{frametitle continuation}\fi}}% 
  \gdef\beamer@frametitle{#2}% 
  \gdef\beamer@shortframetitle{#1}% 
}% 
} 
\makeatother

the problem is that I don't know how to effectively integrate it in my settings... any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Could you please stop to use invalid class options?

Is the \addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-.1in}{} you are referring to? Sorry, I didn't know; it is the only one without the setbeamer but I didn't think it was invalid...

No., I'm referring to the non-existing class option 169

Ah apologies, I saw it on one post and I assumed it was needed to set the aspect-ratio of the slides to 16:9. I've seen also this format: \documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}. Just fixed it; indeed, this changes the slides appearance. Thanks, sorry again! I fixed this post too.

I'd use the headline from the sidebar theme (and use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/722165/36296 to redefine the title page template instead of messing with the content of macros like \author):
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useoutertheme[width=0pt,height=1.5cm]{sidebar}

\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{bground}{HTML}{005EB8}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=anti-flashwhite,bg=bground}

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
    \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=\beamerheadheight]{example-image-b}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overview}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\subsection{First subsection}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This title is \\ on two lines}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This title has}
\framesubtitle{a subtitle}

\end{frame}

\end{document}



I see, thanks for the patience. That's a very clean solution. However, I was wondering if in the title slide I can have set a slightly bigger headline with a logo; I fixed it using the \setbeamertemplate{background canvas} but I don't know whether it's the appropriate solution... Also, it appears that this approach pushes the content of my slides slightly down compare to before; this causes some overlaps with the bottom right logo. Let me know thanks again!

@Matteo I don't think a headline on your title page makes sense. It should be the background of the title instead.

OK, I see. I'm working on a \begin{beamercolorbox} within a \setbeamertemplate{title}. I hope is this the approach you refer to; I will be working on my author filed too; unfortunately, that solution does not print the supervisors for some reason, but I will follow up with some experiments. Thanks again!

@Matteo a beamercolorbox is one possible solution. Another approach would be to create the whole titlepage in tikz. Many options...

Yes, indeed. I think, as I'm bit more confident with the first, I will attempt this for now. If in need, I might open a new issue where I'm stuck.
